# Correlation with Lagged Variable

Tags: instrumental-variables, time-varying-covariate

I am trying to predict the number of hospital visits in year 2.  Lets call that NV2

I want to know if it is related to whether the person had visited the hospital in year one. That is a dummy variable V1

I have non-time varying variables X and time varying variables Z. Let's say Z(1) are their values in year 1 and Z(2) are their values in year 2

It seems to me I can't run a regression of NV2 on X, Z(2), and V1 because V1 is also a function of X.  Do I need to run a logit on V1 using X and Z(1) and then use the predicted V1 as some sort of instrumental variable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to boil down to the following: can I run a regression

$$ y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \varepsilon $$

if $x_2$ is a function of $x_1$?

The short answer is "yes", if $x_2$ is a non-linear function of $x_1$.

Regression assumptions do not restrict cases where $x_2$ is a non-linear function of $x_1$, but you have to be careful when interpreting the coefficients $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$. If $x_2$ moves whenever $x_1$ moves, you cannot say that $\beta_1$ shows the effect on $y$ when $x_1$ changes by one unit -- because $x_2$ will also move and the effect on $y$ will be $\beta_1$ plus $\beta_2$ times whatever the change in $x_2$ due to the unit change in $x_1$.
Meanwhile, if $x_2$ is a linear function of $x_1$, the coefficients $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ will not be uniquely determined, which you do not want.